# Python Dataframe fill nan from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I have a data frame with 3 columns. I want to fill `nan` in the first column with the second column. If there is also `nan` in the second, go to the third column.

My code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,np.nan,np.nan],'B':[15,np.nan,30,np.nan],'C':[np.nan,np.nan,35,40]})

# fill nan in A
xdf['A'].fillna(xdf[['B','C']],inplace=True)
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame"
```

Expected output:

```
xdf = 
      A     B     C
0  10.0  15.0   NaN
1  20.0   NaN   NaN
2  30.0  30.0  35.0
3  40.0   NaN  40.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try via `bfill()`:

```
xdf['A']=xdf.bfill(1)['A']
```

output of `df`:

```
    A       B       C
0   10.0    15.0    NaN
1   20.0    NaN     NaN
2   30.0    30.0    35.0
3   40.0    NaN     40.0
```

**Update:**

if there were additional columns (like D, E) not needed to fillna then select the subset of df and backword fill on axis 1:

```
xdf['A']=xdf[['A','B','C']].bfill(1)['A']
```

Comment: A few questions. What does `.bfill(1)` and `['A']` mean? Also, if there were additional columns (like `D`, `E`) not needed to fillna, how do we handle them?

Comment: @Mainland updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @Mainland `.bfill(1)` or `bfill(axis=1)` means backword fill on axis=1 and `xdf.bfill(1)` is giving a dataframe and we only need column A so we are taking only 1 subset i.e `A` so we are using `['A']`

Comment: Also, this how we specify the columns order `[A,B,C]`? if the order is `[ACB]`, will it first fill with `C` and then `B`?

Comment: @Mainland bcz we are taking this subset `['A','B','C']` so the order remains `ABC`